# prevent sql injection in proc in linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a search form with 3 textboxes (stud_name, stud_city, stud_state). When I enter this vaue `' drop table users` in the name textbox, it will drop the table successfully. Here is my c# code for calling stored procedure. How to prevent this type of injection using linq in c#

```
using (iDataContext db = new iDataContext(connectionString))
{
    var statusList = db.SP_Student_LOOKUP(name, city, state);
    return statusList.ToList<SP_Student_LOOKUPResult>();
}
```

here is my sp

```
CREATE proc SP_Student_LOOKUP @name varchar(50),          

@city varchar(50),          

@state varchar(2)          

as

declare @sql varchar(2048)          

begin           

set @sql = 'select * from student where ';          

if (((@name is not null)) and (len(@name) > 0))          

 set @sql = @sql + ' studentname like ''%'+@name+'%'' and '          

if (((@city is not null)) and (len(@city) > 0))          

 set @sql = @sql + ' studentcity like ''%'+@city+'%'' and '          

if (((@state is not null)) and (len(@state) > 0))          

 set @sql = @sql + ' studentstate like ''%'+@state+'%'' and '         

print @sql          

exec( @sql )
```

Comment: You have to show us the sp

Comment: What's the definition of `db.SP_Student_LOOKUP` and why are you violating the framework design guidelines like it owes you money?​‍

Comment: You should really use some ORM, like Entity Framework or NHibernate, which take care of those things.

Comment: @YuriyN. oh wait, he does (I'm guessing EF by the tag and code), he just doesn't really use it.

Answer (score 3):

Your stored proc is susceptible to sql injection because you're (needlessly) using dynamic sql to build up your query. Don't do this.

Your stored procedure should be

```
CREATE proc SP_Student_LOOKUP 
@name varchar(50), 
@city varchar(50),  
@state varchar(2)  
as

select * from student 
where
 (@name is null or len(@name) = 0 or studentname LIKE  @name)
and (@city is null or len(@city) = 0 or studentcity like @city) 
and (@state is null or len(@state) = 0 or studentstate like @state)
```

This has the same behaviour as your dynamic sql, with 1 caveat - to fully stop the sql injection vulnerability you need to wrap `%` and `%` around your inputs - by doing this inside the stored proc you will re-introoduce the same problem

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Entity Framework, as I'm guessing, you shouldn't be using stored procedures to retrieve data, unless your query is really beyond the capabilities of LINQ (and it isn't). You should build your query in LINQ, like that:

```
using (iDataContext db = new iDataContext(connectionString))
{
     var statusList = from s in db.Set<student>()
                      select s;
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
     {
          statusList = statusList.Where(s => s.studentname.Contains(name));
     }
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
     {
          studentList = studentList.Where(s => s.studentcity.Contains(city));
     }
     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
     {
         studentList = studentList.Where(s => s.studentstate.Contains(state));
     }
     return statusList.ToList();
}
```

and if you're really using the old DataContext object, please read a more recent EF tutorial. This has been superceeded by `DbContext` (where you will find the `.Set<>()` method I used).

Comment: I'm not sure this code is exactly what the OP needs, but this is certainly on the right track. I like the 'use EF for this instead of dynamic SQL or a sproc' concept.

Comment: appreciate your answer but i want dont to do like this way.

Comment: @MuhammadNaveed whether you like it or not, I think it's the most reasonable way if you're already using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @TsahiAsher and @Jamiec
but clearly you are adamant to stick to the dynamic sql,

Given the constraints, I'd suggest that you parameterize your dynamic sql and execute it with the parameters you got.

(note i've also changed the position of "And" statements because if all 3 parameters are empty, you'd get an incomplete sql statement)

[db fiddle Here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=539a59c0ff91a2e3ce333c72e8cd34a8)

```
-- If I recall correct, it has to be NVARCHAR
declare @sql nvarchar(2048)
set @sql = 'select * from student  where 1=1 ';

if ((@name is not null) and (len(@name) > 0))
    set @sql = @sql + 'AND studentname  like ''%''+@name+''%'' '

if ((@city is not null) and (len(@city) > 0))
    set @sql = @sql + 'AND studentcity  like ''%''+@city+''%'' '

if ((@state is not null) and (len(@state) > 0))
    set @sql = @sql + 'AND studentstate  like ''%''+@state+''%'' '

print (@sql)       
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@name VARCHAR(50),@city VARCHAR(50),@state VARCHAR(2)', @name = @name, @city = @city, @state=@state
```

Comment: There is *literally* no point doing this. My change to his SP does exactly the same without slow, lumbering dynamic sql

Comment: yip, totally agree, There is no reason to use dynamic sql at all for this scenario. I'd never put this into my own code. It was purely because he has declined both yours and Tsahi's answer and was insistent on it, so I gave in.

Answer (score -1):

Sanitize the input strings by escaping single quotes within it:

```
using (iDataContext db = new iDataContext(connectionString))
  {
    var statusList = db.SP_Student_LOOKUP(name.Replace("'", @"\'"), city.Replace("'", @"\'"), state.Replace("'", @"\'")
    return statusList.ToList<SP_Student_LOOKUPResult>();
  }
```

Comment: This is a super-naive way to combat SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Although this could work, i really wouldn't recommend to do it like this.